# Property 'name' does not exist on type 'any[]' during ng build--aot

Tags: angular, ng-build

I have 1 dropdown and 1 input field.
Based the selection of dropdown, input field value is set.

So i used an array of type any(Array).

In my .ts file, i wrote like this

```
Services: Array<any>=[
    {name: 'Consultation', price: 100}, 
    {name: 'Follow Up', price: 200}, 
    {name: '24 Hrs. Creatinine', price: 300}, 
    {name: 'Complete Blood Count - CBC', price: 400}, 
    {name: 'X-Ray', price: 500}];

 selectedservice = this.Services;
```

And in HTML, I wrote likes this

```
<div class="col-sm-9">
                <nb-select type="number" fullWidth id="service" [(ngModel)]="selectedservice"
                  [ngModelOptions]="{standalone: true}" required>
                  <nb-option *ngFor="let service of Services" [value]="service">{{service.name}} </nb-option>
                </nb-select>
</div>
<div class="col-sm-9">
                <input type="number" nbInput fullWidth id="price1" [disabled]="true"
                  value="{{selectedservice.price}}" class="form-control" />
```

When I run build command, `ng build --aot`

I was getting this error

Property 'name' does not exist on type 'any[]'.

Property 'price' does not exist on type 'any[]'.

How to resolve this

Comment: You've only provided a small amount of code that has references to unknown things. It looks like something is calling `Services.name` and `Services.price`, but you've not included these

Comment: selectedservice = this.Services;

this varribale selectedservice is used for calling

Comment: That's your problem then.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you want to use an object as the selected value, you should bind to `[ngValue]` in the `<option>` elements. Use `[value]` when the value is a string.

```html
<div class="col-sm-9">
  <nb-select type="number" fullWidth id="service" 
      [(ngModel)]="selectedservice"
      [ngModelOptions]="{standalone: true}" required>
    <nb-option *ngFor="let service of Services" [ngValue]="service">
      {{service.name}} 
    </nb-option>
  </nb-select>
</div>

<div class="col-sm-9">
  <input *ngIf="selectedservice" type="number" nbInput fullWidth id="price1" [disabled]="true"
    value="{{selectedservice.price}}" class="form-control" />
</div>
```

It is also meaningless to initialise your `selectedservice` with the source array. You should set it to one of your options.

```js
selectedservice = this.Services[0];
```

DEMO: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-rg8myc

Answer (score 0):

Always try to provide a valid data type and avoid using any.
It would be better to create an interface and use it in your code.

```
interface ServiceInterface {
  name: string;
  price: number;
}
```

Use this interface in your code.

```
Services: ServiceInterface[] = [
        {name: 'Consultation', price: 100}, 
        {name: 'Follow Up', price: 200}, 
        {name: '24 Hrs. Creatinine', price: 300}, 
        {name: 'Complete Blood Count - CBC', price: 400}, 
        {name: 'X-Ray', price: 500}];
```

when you are using it inside `*ngFor` you want to access the properties of `object`, it means you are assuming it as `object` but in declaration you have created it as `array` of any data type. It is not able find any type information from it and giving you an error.

Comment: This doesn't answer the question though?

Comment: do i need to create ts file to define interface?

Comment: You can create this interface in same file for now but it is good practice to have a separate file.